# Find last created_at record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I find the last record by their created_at field?

`Record.order("created_at").last`

or

`Record.where(:created_at).last`

or

Neither and there is a better way?

Comment: Record.order(created_at: :desc).first

Comment: Thank you @Dapeng114! why ".first" if I'm trying to find the the newest(last) record? wouldn't it be Record.where(created_at: :desc).last ? (I know u have ur reasons and im probably wrong but would like to understand it better)

Comment: My answer is the same with your first option.
```Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `articles`.* FROM `articles` ORDER BY `articles`.`created_at` DESC LIMIT 1```

Comment: @Dapeng114 got it!! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a valid request

```
Record.order(created_at: :desc).first
```

take care of a tree index on this field to have a better performance, though

Comment: So to have the most recent/latest record from the database is it:
``Record.order(created_at: :desc).last``
or 
``Record.order(created_at: :desc).first``
as someone suggest before?
also? tree index?

Comment: sorry, it is `first` of course. or `Record.order(created_at: :asc).last`. Tree index is an "ordered" kind of index that can easily retreive sorted data. Search for "btree index in mysql/postgresql" or other rdbms of your choice.

Answer (score 3):

In Rails, you can also add the line

```
default_scope { order(created_at: :asc) }
```

to the Record model to ensure that Record.last behaves as expected you can find the newest record

You can refer the link [scopes in rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments)